# When is an AsynchronousFileChannel write "complete"?

Tags: java, asynchronous, nio

In Java, when one calls `AsynchronousFileChannel.write(...)` one receives a `Future`, which one can then wait on for completion via `Future.get()`.

When that `get()` call returns, has the write been written to the disk, or just the page cache?

If it matters, the specific platform I'm curious about is Linux & ext4.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html#force(boolean)

It looks like even after the `get` method returns on the `Future`, there some some caches at the operating system level that may prevent the contents from being written to disk. If you want to be really sure, I think you must do a `force` after the `Future` returns.

A relevant excerpt:

> Forces any updates to this channel's file to be written to the storage
>   device that contains it. If this channel's file resides on a local
>   storage device then when this method returns it is guaranteed that all
>   changes made to the file since this channel was created, or since this
>   method was last invoked, will have been written to that device. This
>   is useful for ensuring that critical information is not lost in the
>   event of a system crash.
>
> If the file does not reside on a local device then no such guarantee
>   is made.
>
> The metaData parameter can be used to limit the number of I/O
>   operations that this method is required to perform. Passing false for
>   this parameter indicates that only updates to the file's content need
>   be written to storage; passing true indicates that updates to both the
>   file's content and metadata must be written, which generally requires
>   at least one more I/O operation. Whether this parameter actually has
>   any effect is dependent upon the underlying operating system and is
>   therefore unspecified.
>
> Invoking this method may cause an I/O operation to occur even if the
>   channel was only opened for reading. Some operating systems, for
>   example, maintain a last-access time as part of a file's metadata, and
>   this time is updated whenever the file is read. Whether or not this is
>   actually done is system-dependent and is therefore unspecified.
>
> This method is only guaranteed to force changes that were made to this
>   channel's file via the methods defined in this class.